# What's EE4's best forms solution?

Tags: forms, ee4

I'm trying to teach myself the best tech related to EE4. Now I'm on forms. Before going straight to FreeForm Pro, I'd like to get any opinions on form solutions. Currently looking into Channel Form and deciding whether to even mess with it (already bought FreeForm Pro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of **EE4** [Freeform Pro](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform) will be perfect choice for creating the forms. And if you want to play with **channels** then [Channel Form](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html) comes in the picture. All things depends on your requirement, what you actually need. Both are perfect in their scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Freeform Pro is a solid choice, and has good support.  Depends what you are after - you can do alot with the built in [Channel Form](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html) function.

Also you would do well to be familiar with the marvellous [Snaptcha](https://putyourlightson.com/expressionengine-addons/snaptcha) - **really** effective spam avoidance.

Comment: I've used Snaptcha for years on EE2. Great addon. It looks like the new FreeForm Pro (Next) has built-in spam protection that's supposed to be great. I haven't tested it yet, but SolSpace seems confident about it.